# Как переключиться на другую вкладку в arsenic?

Tags: python, asyncio, handle

Как переключиться на другую вкладку в arsenic (асинхронный аналог selenium)? Если в selenium `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])` работает отлично, то как такое же решение реализовать в arsenic я не знаю, ведь `await session.switch_to.window(session.window_handles[1])` не работает

```
import asyncio
from arsenic import get_session, browsers, services

async def scraper():
    service = services.Chromedriver(binary="./chromedriver.exe")
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get("https://www.google.com")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await session.execute_script("window.open('');")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await session.switch_to.window(session.window_handles[1])
        await session.get("https://www.google.com")

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(scraper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по докам как-то так:

```
await session.switch_to_window((await session.get_window_handles())[1])
```

Comment: Уже и не надеялся что кто-то поможет решить этот вопрос. Спасибо, действительно все работает и переключается хоть на 2-ю, хоть на 5-ю вкладку!